# Angular Dependency Injection parent instance

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-material

I have a working example of customized material accordions https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imnpaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-item.component.ts

It works well.

The only question I have is when I inject `AccordionDirective` into `AccordionItemComponent`, how do angular knows that in particular I need an instance of parent `AccordionDirective` and it correctly gives me that instance?

---

**Upd**

In `CdkAccordionItem` there's [_expansionDispatcher](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/accordion/accordion-item.ts#L103-L108) which fires each time when accordion-item is expanded so the other items of **this** accordion will be collapsed. And there's a condition check `this.accordion.id === accordionId` that each item is belongs to the same accordion where the event has been occured.

I just can't figure out how do each item gets it `this.accordion`? I mean why if I just import class from `AccordionDirective` in my `AccordionItemComponent` and inject it - in fact it gives exactly the parent instance of `AccordionDirective` (not just first or last or any random instance of any other accordion in this app)?